# Android. Круговой таймер

Tags: java, android

Как сделать круговой демонстратор оставшегося времени по типу такого:

[image: Circle Timer]

> Предполагаю, что нужно как-то доработать ProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать данную библиотеку https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress